# Why can't I grab a specific objects from my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
for (var statementCounter = 0; statementCounter < 23; statementCounter++) {
  secularScores.push([scores[statementCounter][0], scores[statementCounter][1]]);
  if (sorted == false) {
    secularScores.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b[1] - a[1]
    });
    sorted = true;
  } else {
    console.log(secularScores); // this works
    console.log(secularScores[0]); // this works
    console.log(scores[statementCounter]); // this works
    console.log(scores[statementCounter][0]); // this works
    console.log(secularScores[statementCounter]); // this doesn't work
    console.log(secularScores[statementCounter][0]); // this doesn't work"Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property of '0' of undefined"
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is why the bottom ones don't work.

The array that I push into secularScores works just fine, I can grab any specific object from it, but when I try to grab a specific object from secularScores, it says it's undefined.

```
secularScores[statementCounter] says undefined.
secularScores[statementCounter][0] says Error: cannot read property '0'of undefined.
```

Here's the array (the result of console.log(secularScores))

```
(23) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2),
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ["VVD", "63.33"]
1: (2) ["CDA", "56.67"]
2: (2) ["PVV", "50.00"]
3: (2) ["D66", 18]
4: (2) ["GroenLinks", 14]
5: (2) ["SP", 17]
6: (2) ["PvdA", 15]
7: (2) ["ChristenUnie", 20]
8: (2) ["Partij voor de Dieren", 14]
9: (2) ["SGP", 18]
10: (2) ["DENK", 18]
11: (2) ["Forum voor Democratie", 11]
12: (2) ["Lokaal in de Kamer", 12]
13: (2) ["OndernemersPartij", 15]
14: (2) ["VNL", 10]
15: (2) ["Nieuwe Wegen", 14]
16: (2) ["De Burger Beweging", 13]
17: (2) ["Piratenpartij", 18]
18: (2) ["Artikel 1", 14]
19: (2) ["Libertarische Partij", 16]
20: (2) ["50Plus", 11]
21: (2) ["Vrijzinnige Partij", 14]
22: (2) ["Niet Stemmers", 0]
length: 23
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Can you show the array ?

Comment: impossible - at least with the code you've shown

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(secularScores);`? Or maybe even just the log? It's very hard to recreate your context and I think seeing the logs may help.

Comment: Here's the array (the result of console.log(secularScores))
(only part of it due to character limit)
(23) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ["VVD", "63.33"]
1: (2) ["CDA", "56.67"]
2: (2) ["PVV", "50.00"]
3: (2) ["D66", 18]
4: (2) ["GroenLinks", 14]
5: (2) ["SP", 17]
6: (2) ["PvdA", 15]
7: (2) ["ChristenUnie", 20]
8: (2) ["Partij voor de Dieren", 14]
9: (2) ["SGP", 18]

Comment: It's very difficult to understand, what is going on here... Can you, please, add all needed data (like `scores` array), and describe, what this code should do? It'll be much easier for us to understand you and help with finding an error... Also, there is a great service https://jsfiddle.net/ where you can create an example of NOT working code, and share a link with community :)

Comment: What is the `scores` array? I tried using your `secularScores` array as the `scores` array in your code, and it all worked correctly. Can you make your code into a minimal runnable example, using the JS snippet functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my sort function is messing with my results, causing this issue.
Thank you, everyone, for trying to help me.